# Invalidate already-stored responses with Last-Modified header

Tags: http, http-headers, last-modified, http2

[Section 4 of RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4) has this paragraph:

> When more than one suitable response is stored, a cache MUST use the
> most recent response (as determined by the Date header field).  It
> can also forward the request with "Cache-Control: max-age=0" or
> "Cache-Control: no-cache" to disambiguate which response to use.

It mentioned about invalidating already-stored responses with `Date` or `Cache-Control` headers.

What's about the `Last-Modified` header? Can I use it for the same purpose?

Comment: Which question are you asking: “*Would that conform to RFC 7234?*” or “*Do existing caches implement that?*” ?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov The second one, actually. I just want to know whether or not I can use this header to invalidate those responses.

Comment: It’s not very easy to get an HTTP cache—especially a user agent cache—to store several fresh responses that would be suitable for the same request. This is also not “invalidation.” Are you sure you’re not confusing the situation with something else? It may be a good idea to explain your situation in more detail.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov I actually want to update the old stored response with a new one. And I'm thinking about using `Last-Modified` header for this task. I really have no idea about the situation you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Last-Modified` serves as a validator. These are mentioned earlier in the section you quoted:

> When presented with a request, a cache MUST NOT reuse a stored response, unless […] the stored response is either:

> - fresh (see Section 4.2), or
> - allowed to be served stale (see Section 4.2.4), or
> - successfully validated (see Section 4.3).

[Section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.3) explains validation in detail. I think [4.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.3.2) is of must interest to you:

> [A] request containing an [`If-Modified-Since`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.3) header field indicates that the client wants to validate one or more of its own stored responses by modification date. A cache recipient SHOULD generate a 304 (Not Modified) response (using the metadata of the selected stored response) if one of the following cases is true:

> 1. **the selected stored response has a `Last-Modified` field-value that is
>    earlier than or equal to the conditional timestamp;**
>    2. no `Last-Modified` field is present in the selected stored response, but it has a `Date` field-value that is earlier than or equal to the conditional timestamp; or,
>    3. neither `Last-Modified` nor `Date` is present in the selected stored response, but the cache recorded it as having been received at a time earlier than or equal to the conditional timestamp.

So yes, it is perfectly in line with the RFC to do so. Since `Last-Modified`/`If-Modified-Since` is a pretty old mechanism that got introduced as early as HTTP/1.0, you can expect caches to comply.

Comment: The question seems to be about selecting one of several fresh responses, which does not involve revalidation. However, it’s possible that the question is poorly asked.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov hm, you're actually right. `Last-Modified` does not affect freshness and will only kick in with requests that have an `If-Modified-Since` but no `If-None-Match` header in them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BTW, I actually don't understand the second paragraph. From what I understood, the request must contain the `If-Modified-Since` header in order to validate by `Last-Modified` header. Does this action really force browsers to overwrite the old file when a new one is available? Just because requests do not always contain the `If-Modified-Since` header field.